# Cannot work with the Mulesoft AnyPoint API Designer

Tags: json, raml

I'm working with the API Designer from the AnyPoint-platform (http://anypoint.mulesoft.com/).

Unfortunatelly the designer is currently constantly crashing. I open an .json or .raml file and try to edit it, but suddenently the browser crashes!
(I've tried multiple browsers and software systems.)

Does somebody know why the page is contantly not working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there were issues/outage of Design Center and Exchange in Anypoint platform on 15th Feb.

In future,if you face issues you can directly check the status of the systems at  :
http://status.mulesoft.com/

You can also find Scheduled Maintenance and all previous issues on this site as well.